# what I need to change in my code to get my output like this [None, 2, None, 4,None].I am using lambd function to do this

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to do this :

```
evenList = ((lambda x : x if x%2==0 else None), [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Expected output :

```
[None,2,None,4,None,6]
```

I am getting :

```
(<function __main__.<lambda>>, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: dont use lambda. just use a list comp.

Comment: lambda + map or list comp (I suggest the second option)

Comment: You want `[x if x%2==0 else None for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just created a tuple, Not using that lambda,

Change your code like this,

```
In [10]: list(map((lambda x : x if x%2==0 else None), [1,2,3,4,5,6]))                                                                                                                                       
Out[10]: [None, 2, None, 4, None, 6]
```

Better use list comprehension,

```
In [11]: [i if i%2==0 else None for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]]                                                                                                                                                      
Out[11]: [None, 2, None, 4, None, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply using:

```
>>> [x if x%2==0 else None for x in range(1,7)]
[None, 2, None, 4, None, 6]
```